# Working with file in Qt 5.1

Tags: c++, qt, fstream, ifstream

I load a file and need to calculate the number of elements in it as follows :

```
int kmean_algorithm::calculateElementsInFile()
{
    int numberOfElements = 0;
    int fileIterator
    QFile file("...\\iris.csv");
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(0, "Error", file.errorString());
    }
    if(file.isOpen())
    {
        while(file >> fileIterator)
        {
            numberOfElements ++;
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
```

The code provided is wrong and I realize it, as `>>` is from `fstream` (if I loaded the file with standard c++ as follows `ifstream file(filename);` there would be no problem), as I load the file using `QFile` it means that `file >> fileIterator` is impossible w.r.t the following error about types inequality:

> error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'QFile' and 'int')

Q: How can I make `>>` in my case to work? Any suggestion? Alternatives?

Comment: 1) Use forward slashes when dealing with paths in Qt 2) Perhaps you're looking for QTextStream.

Comment: @peppe 1)Do you mean writing "...//iris.csv" instead of "...\\iris.csv"? 2) What it does, is it same with functionality?

Comment: [QTextStream](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtextstream.html#details)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The QTextStream class allows you to construct it with a QIODevice, which happens to be what QFile is derived from. Therefore, you can do something like this: -

```
QFile file(".../iris.csv"); // Note the forward slash (/) as mentioned in the comments
if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    QMessageBox::warning(0, "Error", file.errorString());
}

// Use a text stream to manipulate the file
QTextStream textStream(&file);

// use the stream operator, as desired.
textStream >> numberOfElements;
```

Note that a single forward slash in paths (/) is acceptable for Qt instead of an escaped backslash (\\) for all paths. The forward slash is also the normal way of defining paths in operating systems other than Windows, such as Linux and OSX.